# Api Call Error in Xcode 7 / iOS 9 (how to setup App Transport Security in plist)

Tags: ios, httprequest, ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

I am using xcode 7 beta version.
Now, I am working an API. If, I use the API in Xcode 6.3 it works fine but when same API I used in xcode 7 error message appears Unable to parse.

[here is the API i am using](http://23.239.29.156/burblecore/rest/v3.2/cfe_auth/jumper_login?email=AwGNQhVfRh%20GOUTr1dEfOA3hSrI294AcnrrIQMRHvxAaIOZYk/w7mNcP05u6XjbaFr8C1KpByZMm89/ITFrATui65hT4yFDuJn5de1EIN%20Wbm7PLoMCAoRmGLa6gYN8KaoQ=&password=AwGfA3yzVElhyx1LSDchtdxYAVD0JMn1ovOojn/gUxZxD/CZet8tMegPxSBHaORRbJGrpwfbpHdllGGgXZKBgnZRbaRJWxIuplQWyBZbzPDWxQ==)

Please help me out.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's not an API that's XML data.

Comment: yes it is an xml data but in xcode 7 response is not getting it shows nil

Comment: Do you think showing your code might help solve the issue, or do you expect us to guess how you've implemented your solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iOS9, Apple added new feature called App Transport Security(ATS).

ATS enforces best practices during network calls, including the use of HTTPS.

Apple Pre-release documentation:

> ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior,
>   and is easy to adopt. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible,
>   regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an
>   existing one.
>
> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If
>   you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can
>   right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as
>   soon as possible.

Add Below key in your info.plist & then see.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Even you can add specific exception,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

        ...

    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this easy steps..

Add the following in you info.plist
[image]

`NSAppTransportSecurity

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` 
 This will help you.

Comment: Works fine
NSAppTransportSecurity
   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads it will be help full....

Comment: `NSAppTransportSecurity   

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`