# Xcode:App Transport Security

Tags: ios, xcode

At first, I cannot request the network,so I got the way:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But there turned up the question:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

Someone know this ? help!

Comment: Your answer is here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: @廖马儿 Check my answer.

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33095901/5388289)

Comment: @mitul marsonia I have saw all of those, but no use.

Comment: Accepted answer same as my comment answer please check it.

Comment: I have already mentioned the same as accepted answer. At least you should upvote if you can not accept the answer in the case of helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change the Settings you need to change,Target -> Info
[image]

Comment: I fond TARGETS->Info ,In it, there is no NSAppTransportSecurity ，and I also cannot add it.

Comment: OK,this help me very much! I solved the issue, cheers! thank u, @Shangari C

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I use IP, and there is no domain, can I test the server.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add External Hosts as a string with item 0 having * value in `Info.plist`. Check below image:

[image]

And,

Add below details: App Transport Security Settings as Dictionary and add Allow Arbitrary Loads to true.

Check underneath image:

[image]

**Hope this will solve your problem.**

Comment: It did not work:
the error is :‘error==The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.’

Comment: What is not working for you? Have added App Transport Security Settings in Info.plist?

Comment: I have already mentioned the same as accepted answer. At least you should upvote if you can not accept the answer in the case of helpful answer.