# How to save the data in JSON dictionary and to send the web service post call?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two text field called password field and i saves that text in one string called "Firststring".

My doubt is how can I assign the string value to my jsonDict and to make the web service post call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are in the right way, you can directly add your String to Dict using Keys

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setObject:@"staticname" forKey:@"albert"];
[jsonDict setObject:Firststring forKey:@"password"];
```

**update-1**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL HERE"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSError *error = nil;

   NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setObject:@"staticname" forKey:@"albert"];
[jsonDict setObject:Firststring forKey:@"password"];

 NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict 
options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data length]];
[req addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                            // Do something 
           NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);  
                                        }];

[task resume];
```

**Choice-2**

```
// 1
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_WEBSERVICE_URL"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

// 2
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]  initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

 // 3
   NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setObject:@"staticname" forKey:@"albert"];
[jsonDict setObject:Firststring forKey:@"password"];

 NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict 
options:kNilOptions error:&error];


if (!error) {
 // 4
 NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session  uploadTaskWithRequest:request
fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse  *response,NSError *error) {
// Handle response here
  // handle response
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
}];

// 5
[uploadTask resume];
```

**Note** - *if you want to hit the server in iOS 9 you need to add the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in your .PList*  for E.g see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889312/api-call-error-in-xcode-7-ios-9-how-to-setup-app-transport-security-in-plist)

Comment: So after that i dont know how to pass the data to my data base.For example my url is :` http :// some xample/api`I need to pass these json data to my server Then how to do that.I am asking about the web service call.How to do that

Comment: Ok ,Then where i will pass the parameters to url.Can you please add your two code and update so that i can learn how to code and where to pass the jsonDict

Comment: @mack - for example see here https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Comment: So your two choice is sending the parameter to api in json format right ??

Comment: Really help full.I will work on json calling and get back ..Thanks for your precious time

Comment: @mack - really happy , do well , if you need a support related to this ask here , I will help and accept answer if useful

Comment: i have one doubt .Which is input and which is parameter in ns dictionary..for example ` [jsonDict setValue:@"AppleID" forKey:@"mark@gmail.com"];`  In this is correct or ` [jsonDict setValue:@"mark@gmail.com" forKey:@"AppleID"];`

Comment: @mack - this is correct `[jsonDict setValue:@"mark@gmail.com" forKey:@"AppleID"];`

Comment: Okay and what is this :  ` options:kNilOptions error:&error`

Comment: why we use KNillOptions

Comment: @mack - we can NSJSONReadingOptions in using 4 types , typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSJSONReadingOptions) {
    NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
    NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves = (1UL << 1),
    NSJSONReadingAllowFragments = (1UL << 2)
} N, if we no need anytype we can directly use 0 or KNilOptions  = 0

Comment: i have tried its worked fine.But after one min.My app getting crash for "data parameter in nill"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929804/uncaught-exception-nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-data-parameter-is-nil

Answer (score 0):

use the following methods to post data.

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:self.txtUsername.text forKey:@"txt_user_email"];
        [dict setObject:self.txtPassword.text forKey:@"txt_user_pass"];
        [self postMethodWithDict:dict andURL:@"http:your API url here" ];

}



-(void) postMethodWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict andURL:(NSString *)url{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\\r\\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"sending data  %@", dict);

    // additional method to call in between
    NSData *data = [self createFormData:dict withBoundary:boundary];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\r\\n--%@\\r\\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body  appendData:data];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    if(conn) {
        // connection success
        NSLog(@"connection success");
    }
    else {
        // deal with error
        NSLog(@"error occured");
    }
}


//  linked method
- (NSData*)createFormData:(NSDictionary*)myDictionary withBoundary:(NSString*)myBounds {
    NSMutableData *myReturn = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSArray *formKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [formKeys count]; i++) {
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",myBounds] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@",[formKeys objectAtIndex:i],    [myDictionary valueForKey:[formKeys objectAtIndex:i]]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
    return myReturn;
}
```

> use NSURLConnection delegate methods to get over all response of your api

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"staticname":@"albert",
                           @"password":password};
```