# POST Method With Multiple JSON Objects(Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, json, http, post

Hello everyone I m trying to send two json objects in one request.
Here is what I did so far:

```
NSDictionary *credentials = [request getCredentials];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
req.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *error = nil;

     NSData *o = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:output
                                                    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

     NSData *c = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:credentials
                                                 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];



     NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:o encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"DATA: %@",myString);


     if (!error) {
         NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:req
                                                                    fromData:c completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {

                                                                        NSLog(@"RESPONSE %@", response);
                                                                    }];


         [uploadTask resume];
     }
```

In this code I send only "NSData *c" but also I want to send "NSData *o" in the same request. Is it possible, I need your helps. Thanks.

Comment: you mean to say that you want to send more then one dict(json data) in a single request ?

Comment: @vaibhav exactly that is what i m trying to say

Comment: so why cant you merge you data into the single dictionary or is there any  condition with second dict data to upload ?

Comment: According to API they asked for multiple parameters in one request

Comment: all the parameters shud go in a dictionary.

Comment: okay you could send multiple parameters using single dict have look http://stackoverflow.com/a/38913944/4003548 sure it will be useful ..

Answer (score 1):

you can combine dictonaries into one using below code then post to server.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *configuration;
    ...
    -(NSMutableDictionary*) configuration{
    if (!_configuration) {
         NSDictionary *core_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"installation" ofType:@"plist"]];
         NSDictionary *app_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to"] pathForResource:@"something/data" ofType:@"plist"]];
         [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary: core_config];
         [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary: app_config];
         NSLog(@"merged: %lu, core: %lu, app: %lu", (unsigned long)[_configuration count],  (unsigned long)[core_config count],  (unsigned long)[app_config count]);
         // merged: 0, core: 4, app: 5
      }
    return _configuration;
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//passing key as a http header request 
[theRequest addValue:@"value1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key1"];

//passing key as a http header request
[theRequest addValue:@"value2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key2"];